# Round up a number in the v-model in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i want to round up this number in my input:

```html
    <b-form-input id="amount_input" type="number"
     v-model="Math.ceil(form.contract.reward_cents / 100)"
      :state="validate(form.contract.reward_cents)"/>
```

I tried to do Math.ceil() but i'm getting this error
[image]

Can anyone help me fix it?

I solved it like this:

```js
    computed: {
        reward_cents () {
           return Math.ceil(this.form.contract.reward_cents / 100);       
        },
    }
```

```html
<template>
<b-form-input id="amount_input" type="number" v-model="reward_cents"
    :state="validate(form.contract.reward_cents)"/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to use a `computed property` in `v-model` instead of an `expression`.

```
<b-form-input id="amount_input" type="number"
     v-model="reward_cents"
      :state="reward_cents"/>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      reward_cents: {
        get() {
          return this.form.contract.reward_cents;
        },
        set(val) {
          this.form.contract.reward_cents = Math.ceil(val / 100);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can follow:

```
<b-form-input 
id="amount_input" 
type="number"
:value="form.contract.reward_cents"
v-model="reward_cents"
@change="OnChange"
:state="validate(form.contract.reward_cents)"/>

data(){
    return: {
        reward_cents: 0
    }
}

methods: {
    OnChange(newVal){
        this.reward_cents = Math.ceil(newVal / 100);
    }
}
```